# How to remove tomcat-embedded dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, weblogic12c

I have a spring boot application that I want to deploy on weblogic, so I don't need the embedded tomcat dependency (it will crash otherwise).

This spring boot application also includes a library jar that, only to compile, needs the spring-boot-starter-web dependency. So, I did the following poms with "provided" for tomcat dependencies..nervetheless in the final .war the tomcat is still there! Is there a way to see where it's coming from? It is not necessary as manually removing it from my .war makes it work successfully...

**mylibrary.pom**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

myapplication.pom

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myself</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-library</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-22</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**edit**
Running maven dependency:tree says that it is provided, so why it is in the war?

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.31:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.31:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.31:provided
```

Comment: You can run `mvn dependency:tree` to see which dependency comes from where.

Comment: Edited...I still can't understand :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided dependency for tomcat was correct, my problem was that I needed to make a mvn clean before: the target directoy still had the tomcat dependency and it was included in the war.